# Пытаюсь реализовать распознование голоса и аудио в aiogram на python

Tags: python, aiogram

Я сделал бота для телеграм на aiogram, вот код

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['voice', 'audio'])
async def Voice_and_Audio_recognizer(message: types.Message):
    if message.voice: 
        file_id = message.voice.file_id       
    elif message.audio:
        file_id = message.audio.file_id
    newFile = await bot.get_file(file_id)
    if message.voice:
        await newFile.download(f'Nozomi_bot_Telegram\\Voice_and_Audio_user\\voice.ogg') 
    elif message.audio:
        await newFile.download(f'Nozomi_bot_Telegram\\Voice_and_Audio_user\\audio.mp3')        
###Конвертация файла###
    if message.voice:
        src_filename = f'Nozomi_bot_Telegram\\Voice_and_Audio_user\\voice.ogg'
    elif message.audio:
        src_filename = f'Nozomi_bot_Telegram\\Voice_and_Audio_user\\audio.mp3'
    if message.voice:        
        dest_filename = f'Nozomi_bot_Telegram\\Voice_and_Audio_user\\voice_output.wav'
    elif message.audio:
        dest_filename = f'Nozomi_bot_Telegram\\Voice_and_Audio_user\\audio_output.wav'
    process = subprocess.run([f'Nozomi_bot_Telegram\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe', '-i', src_filename, dest_filename, '-y'])
###Распознование слов###    
    try:
        user_audio_file = AudioFile(dest_filename)
        with user_audio_file as source:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
            user_audio = r.record(source)
        text = r.recognize_google(user_audio, language='ru-RU')
    except:
        await message.reply('Я тебя не понимаю, БАКА, повтори еще раз')
```

[image: Мне выдает ошибку]

У меня проблема с тем что аудио не скачивается